# MAMP PRO 4 won't start with cache_module enabled

Tags: apache, caching, mamp

I'm trying to disable cache_module in MAMP 4 so I can develop my site without having to clear the cache all the time, but apache doesn't seem to want to start if I disable cache_module.

MAMP says to look at the log file, but there are no errors in there.

I can disable and re-enable other modules, but if I disable cache_module, apache doesn't start. If I re-enable the module, everything works fine.

For reference, I'm working with Drupal 8 and trying to disable cache as per this article (https://www.drupal.org/node/2598914) and I've done everything except disable cache_module on MAMP 4 as mentioned on this page.

Any thoughts about how to tell what the issue is?

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out I needed to disable a couple other cache modules as well. After disabling all of the following modules, I was able to get apache to start back up.

cache_module
disk_cache_module
mem_cache_module